# Meteor Angular2 subscribe details no data after reload

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, publish-subscribe

i have following problem with Meteor using Angular2 to subscribe my data from collection.

Its all working fine when i just load the list and click on edit.

All Data is there. But if i change something and the server restarts and therefor the page is reloading, or if i just try to get to that edit page using the direkt link, i get the following error in my console:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>   ...

It must have something to do with "subscribe", if i just follow a link from the App its working, cause all the Data from the Objects is there and the `Collection.findOne(this._id)` is working.

But after reload, the subscription of the whole list is missing or something like that, i actually dont know how to fix it.

Now some Code:

**games.component.ts**

```
 ...
        ngOnInit() {

            this.gamesSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe("games").subscribe(() => {
                this.games = Games.find({}).zone();
            });
        }
...
```

**games-edit.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.gameForm = this.fb.group({
        name: new FormControl(),
        questions: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.game = Games.findOne(this.route.params._value.gameId); // Needed cause that hole MeteorObservable stuff is not working

    this.paramsSub = this.route.params
        .map(params => params['gameId'])
        .subscribe(gameId => {
            this.gameId = gameId;

            this.gameSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('game', this.gameId).subscribe(() => {
                MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {
                   return this.game = Games.findOne(this.gameId);
                });
            });

            this.setName(this.game.name);
            this.setQuestions(this.game.questions);
        });


}
```

Comment: It is happening because when the page is loaded for the first time it tries to read property `name`, but it's undefined(subscription isn't ready). I don't use Angular so I don't know how to exactly do it, but in my app which uses VueJS I am waiting for the subscription to be ready and then I show my documents. Until subscription ready returns false I'm showing loading.

Comment: i tryed but somhow its not working, i dont know where to place it